# Are RGB-images in Keras represented as [R,G,B], [R,G,B], ... or as [RR.., GG.., BB..]?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, rgb

Say we have a 3x3 RGB image.

Which of the following representations is correct?

```
[ R, G, B],               [ R, R, R],
[ R, G, B],     OR        [ G, G, G], 
[ R, G, B]                [ B, B, B]
```

I purposely left out the outer parenthesis as how they are set is part of the anwer to my question

Comment: I just found it out by myself. It seems to be first option: [R,G,B], [R,G,B] ,...
Thank you for coming to my Ted Talk! 
;-)

Answer (score 0):

In Keras (and most other places), "R", "G", and "B" are referred to as "channels". By default, the channels are the last dimension of the tensor. This means that each image is an array of rows, and each row is an array of pixels, and each pixel is an array of 3 colors/channels. To answer your exact question, that is most closely represented by your first example rather than your second.

However, Keras can also be configured to use `channels_first`, which means that it's the opposite. In this case, an image is an array of 3 channels, and each channel is a monochrome 2D array of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you are asking unclear question:

- **3x3 RGB image is usually represented as a 3x3x3 array**

that means if your question is about a 3x3 RGB image it should contain three 3x3 array each containing values of one color which can be visualized as:

```
{[(R, R, R),   [(G, G, G),   [(B, B, B),
  (R, R, R),    (G, G, G),    (B, B, B),
  (R, R, R)],   (G, G, G)],   (B, B, B)]}
```

- **Your question actually visualises 3x1 RGB image**

in which case (3x1 RGB image) this version in your question should be correct (maybe after transposition):

```
{[ R, R, R],
 [ G, G, G], 
 [ B, B, B]}
```

If I am wrong, please feel free to edit or correct my answer!